# How do i get a list of object in a Listbox?

Tags: c#, list, winforms, object, listbox

I was trying to create a personal list using WinForms. I try to create a new entry via button click. I have a list of objects with string properties `Name` and `Number`.

How can I show the list of objects in my ListBox?

```
namespace sometestname
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        private void Personallistshow(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void NewItemButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Personallist.Add(new Entrys() { Name = NameBox.Text, Number = Numbox.Text });
        }

        public List<Entrys> Personallist= new List<Entrys>();
    }

        public partial class Entrys
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Number { get; set; }

        }
}
```

The user has 2 Textboxfields. If they click the `NewItemButton`, than create a new `Entrys` object. This new `Entrys` object should be added to `Personallist` object and ListBox should show the updated list.

Comment: Where are you filling the ListBox? Have you set the `ListBox.DataSource` and `DisplayMember`/`ValueMember` properties somewhere? Have you tested a BindingList instead of a simple List?

Comment: If you really want to show those objects in a ListBox __you need to add a ToString() override__ to you class or else the Items will not be able to show something useful; they would show just the class name.. Example : `public partial class Entry
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}` - Also: Do watch your spelling: Change _i, entrys, creat, click, tryed_ to _I, entries, create clicks, tried_.

Comment: Set the `ListBox.DataSource` to your `Personallist`, `DisplayMember` to `"Name"` and `ValueMember` to `"Number"`. You can also use a public property that defines a specific `look` (a combinations of pre-formatted values) and use that as `DisplayMember`. Or, as TaW suggested, override the `ToString()` method of your class. Also, test the BindingList, to see what changes. Maybe coupled with a BindingSource, if, reading the Docs about it, you find it interesting.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Entrys> someList = ...;
Personallist.DataSource = someList;
```

Comment: Also need to either set `Personallist.DisplayMember` and `Personallist.ValueMember`, or override the `ToString()` method of the `Entrys` object

Answer (score 1):

You should use a bindinglist and set the datasourcebinding after initializing your form.

Something like:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public BindingList<Entrys> Personallist = new BindingList<Entrys>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        comboBox1.DataSource = Personallist;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "Number";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Personallist.Add(new Entrys() { Name = "TESTNAME", Number = "TESTNR" });
    }
}
public partial class Entrys
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Always set `DisplayMember` before setting the `DataSource` :)